# Select every row as a list of strings in android room library

Tags: android, database, android-room

I have a database table in Room with this scheme:

```
data class TestModel(
    val name: String,
    val phone: String,
    val description: String,
    val date: String,
    val profession: String,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null
)
```

and I want to select every row as a list of strings. For example with a row with this data:

```
    name = "testName"
    phone = "123456"
    description = "test"
    date: "2021/7/26"
    profession = "none"
    id: Int? = 1
```

I want to have this output:

```
arrayOf(arrayOf<String>("testName", "123456", "test", "2021/7/26", "none", "1"))
```

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the basis i.e. the core Dao that would extract data as

```
"testName", "123456", "test", "2021/7/26", "none", "1"
```

Could be :-

```
@Query("SELECT name||','||phone||','||description||','||date||','||profession||','||id FROM testmodel")
abstract fun getColumnsAsCSV(): List<String>
```

If you wanted an `ArrayList<List<String>>` with each row being an element of the ArrayList containing a list of strings,1 for each column then you could (if using an abstract class as opposed to an interface for the @dao) use something like :-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDao {

    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(testModel: TestModel): Long
    @Query("SELECT name||','||phone||','||description||','||date||','||profession||','||id FROM testmodel")
    abstract fun getColumnsAsCSV(): List<String>

    fun getColumnsAsListList(): ArrayList<List<String>> {
        var rv: ArrayList<List<String>> = ArrayList()
        val t = getColumnsAsCSV()
        for (s: String in t) {
            rv.add(s.split(","))
        }
        return rv
    }
}
```

- However, the latter, could simply be obtained from the TestModel objects. Or just splitting the initial extract.

If the database contained :-

[image]

Then using :-

```
    /* Just extract the CSV */
    val t = dao.getColumnsAsCSV()
    for (s: String in t) {
        Log.d("TSTMDLINFO","String = $s")
    }
    /* extract as ArrayList<List<String>> */
    val tt = dao.getColumnsAsListList()
    var i = 0
    var ii = 0
    for(l: List<String> in tt) {
        i++
        ii = 0
        for (s: String in l) {
            ii++
            Log.d("TSTMDLINFO","Row # = $i String # = $ii String = $s")
        }
    }
```

Results in :-

```
2021-07-26 19:49:25.297 D/TSTMDLINFO: String = testName,123456,test,2021/7/26,none,1
2021-07-26 19:49:25.297 D/TSTMDLINFO: String = testName,123456,test,2021/7/26,none,2
2021-07-26 19:49:25.297 D/TSTMDLINFO: String = testName,123456,test,2021/7/26,none,3


2021-07-26 19:49:25.323 D/TSTMDLINFO: Row # = 1 String # = 1 String = testName
2021-07-26 19:49:25.323 D/TSTMDLINFO: Row # = 1 String # = 2 String = 123456
2021-07-26 19:49:25.323 D/TSTMDLINFO: Row # = 1 String # = 3 String = test
2021-07-26 19:49:25.323 D/TSTMDLINFO: Row # = 1 String # = 4 String = 2021/7/26
2021-07-26 19:49:25.323 D/TSTMDLINFO: Row # = 1 String # = 5 String = none
2021-07-26 19:49:25.323 D/TSTMDLINFO: Row # = 1 String # = 6 String = 1
2021-07-26 19:49:25.323 D/TSTMDLINFO: Row # = 2 String # = 1 String = testName
2021-07-26 19:49:25.324 D/TSTMDLINFO: Row # = 2 String # = 2 String = 123456
2021-07-26 19:49:25.324 D/TSTMDLINFO: Row # = 2 String # = 3 String = test
2021-07-26 19:49:25.324 D/TSTMDLINFO: Row # = 2 String # = 4 String = 2021/7/26
2021-07-26 19:49:25.324 D/TSTMDLINFO: Row # = 2 String # = 5 String = none
2021-07-26 19:49:25.324 D/TSTMDLINFO: Row # = 2 String # = 6 String = 2
2021-07-26 19:49:25.324 D/TSTMDLINFO: Row # = 3 String # = 1 String = testName
2021-07-26 19:49:25.324 D/TSTMDLINFO: Row # = 3 String # = 2 String = 123456
2021-07-26 19:49:25.324 D/TSTMDLINFO: Row # = 3 String # = 3 String = test
2021-07-26 19:49:25.324 D/TSTMDLINFO: Row # = 3 String # = 4 String = 2021/7/26
2021-07-26 19:49:25.324 D/TSTMDLINFO: Row # = 3 String # = 5 String = none
2021-07-26 19:49:25.325 D/TSTMDLINFO: Row # = 3 String # = 6 String = 3
```